# Best Word for "Loyalty to an Alma Mater"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What word or phrase best describes a sense of loyalty to and/or support of an educational institution from which one graduated?

**Used in a sentence:**

> Alice received her PhD from Foo State University (FSU). She actively promotes her alma mater, attends alumni events, and makes large contributions. She has a strong sense of **__**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say *school pride*, although you can say *school spirit* too.

The reason I chose school pride is that school spirit often notes a loyalty while you are going to school somewhere and school pride can be used in either case, however the terms are both used interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the  loyalty to her university can derive  from  *a strong sense of belonging* to her alma mater.

Answer (score 0):

*School loyalty* or *affiliation.*

Comment: *Affiliation* doesn't imply any affection or loyalty on either party, simply that a relationship exists. The university may wish it had never admitted me and I may despise it in return, but the fact of my matriculation means we are nevertheless affiliated.